# RSpec Failing test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

rspec/spec/controllers/javascript_controller_spec.rb

```
describe '#show' do
  context 'when the javascript can be found' do
    subject { get :show, params: { id: javascript.id } }
    it { is_expected.to have_http_status(:ok) }
    it 'returns the correct body' do
      expect(subject.body).to eq(javascript.to_json)
    end
  end
  context 'When the javascript can\'t be found' do
    subject { get :show, params: { id: 'blahdeblah' } }
    it { is_expected.to have_http_status(:not_found)}
    it 'returns an error' do
      expect(subject.body).to eq("{\"code\":404,\"message\":\"Javascript with id 'blahdeblah' not found\"}")
    end
  end
end
```

controllers/javascript_controller

```
class JavascriptController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def show
    javascript = Javascript.find(params[:id])
    javascript_hash = Rails.cache.fetch(javascript.cache_key) {javascript.as_json }
    render json: javascript_hash, status: :ok
  end
  # ...
end
```

So my first two test are passing but my last two aren't.

```
 I'm getting the error 1) JavascriptController#show When the javascript 
 can't be found returns an error
 Failure/Error: javascript = Javascript.find(params[:id])

 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
   Couldn't find Javascript with 'id'=blahdeblah
```

its throwing two of the same errors actually for the last two. I'm trying to test for if the ID is not in the DB then throw an error for not found. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You're writing a **controller spec**, which is a relatively low-level spec: it will invoke your controller action, but any exception raised from there (like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`) will bubble straight up into your spec.

To see a more comprehensive view of what will happen with real requests, use a **request spec** instead. That will pass its request through the full stack, and the exception will then be turned into a 404 response of some sort, as it will in production.

Comment: how come the request test for the record being found works but not found?

Comment: Thats pretty obvious? The failing spec raises an exception that is not caught.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say this but [RTFM](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find).  `.find` throws [RecordNotFound](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) if the "id" cant be found.  Your controller is raising an error before it gets to the render line.

In short, the test isn't broken.  Your controller doesn't conform to the tests that are written in the test suite so you need to update your controller code so that the test will pass.  This is basic Test Driven Development (TDD).  Update your controller code so all the tests pass.